# Parse Json with unknown variables

Tags: swift

I'm trying to parse a Json with unknown keys. The Json looks like this:

```
{[
  "stats": {
    "total": {
      "dagegen gestimmt": 196,
      "nicht beteiligt": 41,
      "dafür gestimmt": 435,
      "enthalten": 37
    },
    "party_A": {
      "dagegen gestimmt": 90,
      "nicht beteiligt": 2
    },
    "party_B": {
      "dafür gestimmt": 230,
      "nicht beteiligt": 16
    },
    "party_C": {
      "dagegen gestimmt": 1,
      "nicht beteiligt": 1
    },
    "party_D": {
      "dagegen gestimmt": 31,
      "enthalten": 35,
      "nicht beteiligt": 1
    },
    "party_E": {
      "dagegen gestimmt": 64,
      "nicht beteiligt": 5
    },
  }
]}
```

The problem is that A: that not every element of "stats" has the same parties and B: Of the 4 possible keys (seen in "total") not all have to be in a party object.

Comment: Show us what you've tried and we can help you tweaking your code.

Comment: This is definitely doable, but it would help to know what you would like the final structures to look like. Where would you like the values of `total` to go, or should that be ignored (I assume it duplicates the other info)? Are the tags in the `party` fields always the same (just sometimes missing)?

Comment: (In your example, total is not the sum of the values in the list; it's not clear whether this is intentional, or just an artifact of how you created the example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with B: Declare the struct members as optional

```
struct Vote {
    let aye, no, abstained, absent : Int?
}
```

A: Decode `stats` as `[String:Vote]` and enumerate the keys

---

If you are responsible for the JSON consider a more reasonable format for example send `stats` as array and move the name of the party into `Vote`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your JSON is somewhat incorrect, and I've made some assumptions about how you want this to work, but here's how I would approach it.

First, here is the JSON I believe you mean (I've removed the extra `[]`, which are syntactically incorrect):

```
let json = Data("""
{
  "stats": {
    "total": {
      "dagegen gestimmt": 196,
      "nicht beteiligt": 41,
      "dafür gestimmt": 435,
      "enthalten": 37
    },
    "party_A": {
      "dagegen gestimmt": 90,
      "nicht beteiligt": 2
    },
    "party_B": {
      "dafür gestimmt": 230,
      "nicht beteiligt": 16
    },
    "party_C": {
      "dagegen gestimmt": 1,
      "nicht beteiligt": 1
    },
    "party_D": {
      "dagegen gestimmt": 31,
      "enthalten": 35,
      "nicht beteiligt": 1
    },
    "party_E": {
      "dagegen gestimmt": 64,
      "nicht beteiligt": 5
    }
  }
}
""".utf8)
```

We need a way to decode a single PartyResult. We can't use Decodable directly here, because we need to pass in the name, but that's ok. We can make our own `init` that accepts a container and a name. I'm assuming you want a default of 0 for values that are missing (rather than making them optional).

```
struct PartyResult {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dagegenGestimmt = "dagegen gestimmt"
        case nichtBeteiligt = "nicht beteiligt"
        case dafürGestimmt = "dafür gestimmt"
        case enthalten
    }

    let name: String
    let dagegenGestimmt: Int
    let nichtBeteiligt: Int
    let dafürGestimmt: Int
    let enthalten: Int

    init(name: String, container: KeyedDecodingContainer<CodingKeys>) throws {
        func decode(_ key: CodingKeys) throws -> Int {
           return try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: key) ?? 0 
        }

        self.name = name
        self.dagegenGestimmt = try decode(.dagegenGestimmt)
        self.nichtBeteiligt = try decode(.nichtBeteiligt)
        self.dafürGestimmt = try decode(.dafürGestimmt)
        self.enthalten = try decode(.enthalten)
    }
}
```

As with many "dictionary key -> property" problems, we'll need some kind of "AnyKey" that can handle arbitrary strings. This is simple one that just handles strings, not integers.

```
struct AnyStringKey: CodingKey, Equatable {
    var stringValue: String
    init(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
    init(_ stringValue: String) { self.init(stringValue: stringValue) }
    var intValue: Int?
    init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
}
```

With that, we can decode the outer `stats` object:

```
struct Stats: Decodable {

    // This could be replaced with AnyStringKey, but just to be explicit.
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey { case stats }

    let partyResults: [PartyResult]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // Get outer container
        let outerContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        // Get inner "stats" container
        let container = try outerContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: AnyStringKey.self, 
                                                           forKey: .stats)

        // Map each entry to a result
        self.partyResults = try container.allKeys
            .filter { $0 != AnyStringKey("total") } // Assuming you want to ignore the total key
            .map { name in
                try PartyResult(name: name.stringValue,
                                container: container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: PartyResult.CodingKeys.self,
                                                                     forKey: name))
        }
    }
}

let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(Stats.self, from: json).partyResults


▿ 5 elements
  ▿ __lldb_expr_20.PartyResult
    - name: "party_A"
    - dagegenGestimmt: 90
    - nichtBeteiligt: 2
    - dafürGestimmt: 0
    - enthalten: 0
  ▿ __lldb_expr_20.PartyResult
    - name: "party_D"
    - dagegenGestimmt: 31
    - nichtBeteiligt: 1
    - dafürGestimmt: 0
    - enthalten: 35
  ▿ __lldb_expr_20.PartyResult
    - name: "party_B"
    - dagegenGestimmt: 0
    - nichtBeteiligt: 16
    - dafürGestimmt: 230
    - enthalten: 0
  ▿ __lldb_expr_20.PartyResult
    - name: "party_C"
    - dagegenGestimmt: 1
    - nichtBeteiligt: 1
    - dafürGestimmt: 0
    - enthalten: 0
  ▿ __lldb_expr_20.PartyResult
    - name: "party_E"
    - dagegenGestimmt: 64
    - nichtBeteiligt: 5
    - dafürGestimmt: 0
    - enthalten: 0
```